# How to determine if something was copied or cut to the clipboard

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface, rcp, e4

in my @execute method I am able to get the selection out of the clipboard / LocalSelectionTransfer. But I have no idea how to react on that based on how the user has put the content to the clipboard.
I have to decide whether I duplicate or not the content.
This is what I have:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL) Shell shell, @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART) MPart activePart) {
    Clipboard clipboard = new Clipboard(shell.getDisplay());
    TransferData[] transferDatas = clipboard.getAvailableTypes();

    boolean weCanUseIt= false;
    for(int i=0; i<transferDatas.length; i++) {
        if(LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer().isSupportedType(transferDatas[i])) {
            weCanUseIt = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (weCanUseIt) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Object> objects = ((StructuredSelection)LocalSelectionTransfer.getTransfer().getSelection()).toList();
        for(Object o: objects) {
            System.out.println(o.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

any Ideas???

Comment: What is this @Execute method? This is not how you normally deal with selections in other parts. You would only use this for a Paste handler.

Answer (score 0):

You only get something in the clipboard using `LocalSelectionTransfer` if you code a part in your RCP to use this transfer type for a Copy operation. It provides a way to transfer the selection directly.

This transfer type will not be used if something is copied to the clipboard any other way (in this case it might be something like `TextTransfer` or `FileTransfer`).

So you will only be using `LocalSelectionTransfer` to deal with a selection from another part in which case you presumably know how to deal with the objects.

If you are trying to do Copy and Cut then you should do the Cut in the source viewer - but this will remove the selection so you can't use `LocalSelectionTransfer` for that. Use a transfer such as `FileTransfer` or `TextTransfer` which doesn't rely on the current selection.

Comment: The method I posted is for pasting. At the time the user hit ctrl+c or ctrl+x I out the selection of a treeviewer into that LocalSelectionTransfer. This works. But: at the time the user pastes via ctrl+v I have to decide wether to duplicate or move the content of the selection. There is no info how the user put the content into the clipboard / LocalSelectionTransfer.

Comment: If you want to tell the difference you can't use LocalSelectionTransfer. Use one of the other Transfer classes. You will have to do the copy / cut in the source view.